# Dozer - Only mapping fields if destination and source objects have the same field names

Tags: java, mapping, dozer

For whatever reason Dozer is NOT letting me map fields with different names, it's only mapping fields based on the source object.

In my `dozerBeanMapping.xml` file I have:

```
<mapping type="one-way">
    <class-a>data.SourceObject</class-a>
    <class-b>data.DestinationObject</class-b>
    <field>
        <a>someField</a>
        <b>anotherField</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

And for the Objects I have:

```
package data;
public class SourceObject
{
    private String someField = "test";

    public void setSomeField(String someField) { this. someField =  someField; }
    public String getSomeField() { return someField; }
}

package data;
public class DestinationObject
{
    private String anotherField;

    public void setAnotherField(String anotherField) { this.anotherField = anotherField; }
    public Date getAnotherField() { return anotherField; }
}
```

Now if I change the `SourceObject` to include a field called `anotherField` then everything works as expected. In other words the mapping will only work if the fields are the same named the same in both the `DestinationObject` and the `SourceObject`. My understanding is that they didn't need to match and this was the whole reason you defined the fields in the mapping xml file.

Answer (score 1):

It seems Dozer does not load your configuration file and maps classes according to the default configuration (`wildcard=true`).
Check whether `dozerBeanMapping.xml` is loaded. See [Debugging Initialization](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/configuration/configuration.html).

Answer (score 0):

By default dozer map fields by names. That's why when you and `anotherField` to `SourceObject` mapping works.

Probably Dozer does load your mapping file. Dozer loads mapping files automatically from classpath. For other files you need to specify their path. Probably your mapping files are not in classpath.